# Print one index in an Array at a time using onClick and have it appear with a Typewriter-effect

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick

So, I am new to this, but I'm trying to have 1 index at a time from an Array printed in a

-tag, starting from index[0] and going down the array while clicking a button and making all text appear as its being typewritten.

This is my array and the code I'm using to return the specific index, one at a time:

### HTML

```
<button type="button" class="scroll-down"  onclick="document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = nextWord();">Down</button>

  <p id="foo" class="chardelay"></p>
```

### JS

```
var wordArray = [
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'consectetur adipiscing elit',
  'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore'
];


var count = -1;

var nextWord = function() {
  return function() {
    return wordArray[++count % wordArray.length];
  }
}();

var prevWord = function() {
  return function() {
    return wordArray[--count % wordArray.length];
  }
}();
```

That far all is working, but as mentioned in the header I'm trying to have the text appear as its being typewritten. I've found the following code on CodePen. It makes the printed text appear with a typewriter effect. The only problem is ALL the indexes are printed, just with a small delay between them:

```
var aText = new Array(
"There are only 10 types of people in the world:",
"Those who understand binary, and those who don't"
);
var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row

function typewriter()
{
 sContents =  ' ';
 iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex-iScrollAt);
 var destination = document.getElementById("foo");

 while ( iRow < iIndex ) {
  sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
 }
 destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + "_";
 if ( iTextPos++ == iArrLength ) {
  iTextPos = 0;
  iIndex++;
  if ( iIndex != aText.length ) {
   iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
   setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
  }
 } else {
  setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
 }
}
```

BUT I want each index to be printed ONLY when I click the button above (but with the sweet typewriter-effect that the CodePen-code provides). Is there a way to tweek the code I found on CodePen to work with/in my code, or is there another way I should try to tackle this?

Comment: Could you link CodePen please

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //array of words
  var wordArray = [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'consectetur adipiscing elit',
    'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore'
  ];

  var typewriteOutput = document.getElementById("typewriteOutput");
  let underscoreFlashON = "_",underscoreFlashOFF="";
  var iSpeed = 200; // time delay of print out
  var iStartindex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
  var iStopindex = wordArray.join(" ").length-1; // stop printing array at last index


  //*****************************************************intervalWriter interval
  let intervalWriter = setInterval(()=>{
    typewriteOutput.innerHTML=typewriteOutput.innerHTML+wordArray.join(" ")[iStartindex]+underscoreFlashON;
    setTimeout(()=>{typewriteOutput.innerHTML=typewriteOutput.innerHTML.replace(underscoreFlashON,underscoreFlashOFF)},iSpeed/2);
    iStopindex==iStartindex?clearInterval(intervalWriter):iStartindex++;
  },iSpeed);
  //****************************************************************************
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TypeWriter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="typewriteOutput"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrygOZ

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TypeWriter</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="typewriteOutput"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//array of words
var wordArray = [
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'consectetur adipiscing elit',
 'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore'
];

var typewriteOutput = document.getElementById("typewriteOutput");
let underscoreFlashON = "_",underscoreFlashOFF="";
var iSpeed = 200; // time delay of print out
var iStartindex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iStopindex = wordArray.join(" ").length-1; // stop printing array at last index

let intervalWriter = setInterval(()=>{
  typewriteOutput.innerHTML=typewriteOutput.innerHTML+wordArray.join(" ")[iStartindex]+underscoreFlashON;
  setTimeout(()=>{typewriteOutput.innerHTML=typewriteOutput.innerHTML.replace(underscoreFlashON,underscoreFlashOFF)},iSpeed/2);
  iStopindex==iStartindex?clearInterval(intervalWriter):iStartindex++;
 },iSpeed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close but won't keep the typewriter effect at the end of the sentence and doesn't take into consideration the autoscroll. But I'm sure you can work that part in.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="typewriter();">Down</button>

<p id="foo"></p>
```

JavaScript

```js
var aText = new Array(
"There are only 10 types of people in the world:",
"Those who understand binary, and those who don't."
);

var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var destination; 

function typewriter(){
    if(aText && aText.length > 0){
        destination = document.getElementById("foo");

        if(iIndex <= aText[0].length){
            destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[0].substring(0, iIndex) + "_";
            iIndex++;
            setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
        }else{
            destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[0].substring(0, iIndex) + '<br />' ;
            //sContents = destination.innerHTML; uncomment here to have text in new lines
            iIndex = 0;
            aText.shift();
        }
    }
}
```